# Define a iframe size then have it auto resize to browser width

Tags: html, css, iframe, stylesheet

I am embedding an iframe with a defined size {500x320} (just for ratio sake) then I like to have the parent container to auto-resize the whole iframe to the browser width.

But because I have already defined width and height, the iframe is not really resizing or responding to the parent container. I have also attached a screenshot of the iframe is not adjusting to browser width.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="iframe"> </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
    .container {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
}

    .iframe {
    width:500px;
    height:320px;
}
```

[image: View this image]

Comment: You're talking about iframe, but there's only divs in the example code?

Comment: I am a newbie to CSS so please forgive my bad coding skill. The issue currently is that the iframe is not scaling up/down when the browser width changes. The whole point is to clip the iframe 500x320px then allow it to resize based on the browser width.

Comment: If you knew all the needed code, you probably wouldn't ask. But what I want to know, is, do you have an iframe element within the inner div? Also, the image shows a centered box, should an applicaple answer also center the box? If so, perhaps you've some CCS for that too already, it would be great if you could add that CSS to the question too.

Comment: I think it would be yes to both questions. I also think it it would be better if you take a look at it by yourself. here is the link: https://cutit.org/7OXsX

Comment: Umh .. we're here to help you, we're not going to do your job. You know your codebase, it's your task to give us the requested information.

Comment: I never asked to do the job.  I only provided the link so you can examine the problem without any words lost in translation. 

I am using WPBakery page builder for having the background image. I have not coded the background image at all so there is no CSS code that I can provide.

Let's forget all the codes and get back to the main problem. How can I have the iframe to resize to browser width while it's clipped inside a container<div>?

Comment: I already found the answer to my question. @teemu Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add css to the iframe directly. check this.

```css
    .container {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
}

    .iframe {
    width:500px;
    height:320px;
}

.iframe iframe{width:100%; height:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="iframe">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but the problem was not solved. The iframe is not scaling up/down when the browser width changes. The whole point is to clip the iframe 500x320px then allow it to resize based on the browser width.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set width: 100%; and height: 100%;

```css
 .container {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
}

    .iframe {
    width:500px;
    height:320px;
}
.iframe iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="iframe"> 
    <iframe src="https://api.jquery.com/focus/">
    
    </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but the problem was not solved. The iframe is not scaling up/down when the browser width changes. The whole point is to clip the iframe 500x320px then allow it to resize based on the browser width.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. Maybe I did not ask my question properly. The task was to keep the aspect ratio of the frame while allowing to resize to the browser width.

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4aQwT3n2c1Q" height="315" width="560" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}


    .video-container iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

See the Pen
  [Responsive iframe with an Aspect Ratio](https://codepen.io/ashkansharifi/pen/yLydadz)
  on CodePen

I found the solution from [this website](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/)